# knockout js remove function not working for nested table

Tags: javascript, html, knockout.js

I have been trying to remove the formulation elements with the 'Delete comp' link, but I'm not sure why it's not working. Also, the 'Add another composition' link is working once, but not multiple times.
I'm working with Knockout.js and any explanation why this is not working will be greatly helpful.

```js
    $( document ).ready(function() {
var initialData = [
    
];
 
var brandNamesModel = function(brandNames) {
    var self = this;
    self.brandNames = ko.observableArray(ko.utils.arrayMap(brandNames, function(drug) {
        return { brandName: drug.brandName, formulations: ko.observableArray(drug.formulations), compositions: ko.observableArray(drug.compositions) };
    }));
 
    self.addBrandName = function() {
        self.brandNames.push({
            brandName: "",
            formulations: ko.observableArray(),
            compositions: ko.observableArray()
        });
    };
 
    self.removeBrandName = function(drug) {
        self.brandNames.remove(drug);
    };
 
    self.addFormulations = function(drug) {
        drug.formulations.push({
            compositions: ko.observableArray()
        });
    };
 
    self.removeFormulations = function(formulation) {
        $.each(self.brandNames(), function() { this.formulations.remove(formulation) })
    };
    
    self.addComposition = function(drug) {
        drug.compositions.push({
            type: "",
            number: ""
        });
    };
 
    self.removeComposition = function(composition) {
        $.each(self.brandNames(), function() { this.compositions.remove(composition) })
    };
 
    self.save = function() {
        self.lastSavedJson(JSON.stringify(ko.toJS(self.brandNames), null, 2));
    };
 
    self.lastSavedJson = ko.observable("")
};
 
ko.applyBindings(new brandNamesModel(initialData));        
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>
<div class='container'>
   <h2>brandNames</h2>
   <div>
      <table>
         <tr>
            <th>Brand name</th>
            <th>formulations</th>
         </tr>
         <tbody data-bind="foreach: brandNames">
            <tr>
               <td>
                  <input data-bind='value: brandName' />
                  <div><a href='#' data-bind='click: $root.removeBrandName'>Delete brand name</a></div>
               </td>
               <td>
                  <table>
                     <tbody data-bind="foreach: formulations">
                         <tr>
                             <td><label>Formulation</label></td>
                             <td><select>
                                     <option>Tablet</option>
                                     <option>Syrap</option>
                                 </select>
                             </td>
                             <td><a href='#' data-bind='click: $root.removeFormulations'>Delete</a></td>
                                    
                             
                             <td>
                               <table>
                                   <tbody data-bind="foreach: compositions">
                                       <tr>
                                       <td><input data-bind='value: type' /></td>
                                       <td><input data-bind='value: number' /></td>
                                       <td><a href='#' data-bind='click: $root.compositions.removeComposition'>Delete comp</a></td>
                                    </tr>
                                   </tbody>
                               </table>
                              <a href='#' data-bind='click: $root.addComposition'>Add another composition</a>
                           </td>
                         </tr>

                     </tbody>
                  </table>
                  <a href='#' data-bind='click: $root.addFormulations'>Add formulations</a>
               </td>
               
            </tr>
         </tbody>
      </table>
   </div>
   <p>
      <button data-bind='click: addBrandName'>Add a drug</button>
      <button data-bind='click: save, enable: brandNames().length > 0'>Save to JSON</button>
   </p>
   <textarea data-bind='value: lastSavedJson' rows='5' cols='60' disabled='disabled'> </textarea>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you post some dummy data? Without it people would just need to read the code! You can create a working snippet through the code button `<>` in the editor  in case you aren't aware.

Comment: Yes, I've included it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is clear that you need to `formulation` object to remove the `composition`. So in order to get the `formulation` along with `composition`, here's how I would write the click binding:

```
<a href='#' data-bind='click: function() {$root.removeComposition($data, $parent) }'>Delete comp</a>
```

Then, you could write the delete composition function as follows:

```
self.removeComposition = function(composition,formulation ) {
  formulation.compositions.remove(composition);
};
```

```js
$( document ).ready(function() {
var initialData = [
    
];
 
var brandNamesModel = function(brandNames) {
    var self = this;
    self.brandNames = ko.observableArray(ko.utils.arrayMap(brandNames, function(drug) {
        return { brandName: drug.brandName, formulations: ko.observableArray(drug.formulations), compositions: ko.observableArray(drug.compositions) };
    }));
 
    self.addBrandName = function() {
        self.brandNames.push({
            brandName: "",
            formulations: ko.observableArray(),
            compositions: ko.observableArray()
        });
    };
 
    self.removeBrandName = function(drug) {
        self.brandNames.remove(drug);
    };
 
    self.addFormulations = function(drug) {
        drug.formulations.push({
            compositions: ko.observableArray()
        });
    };
 
    self.removeFormulations = function(formulation) {
        $.each(self.brandNames(), function() { this.formulations.remove(formulation) })
    };
    
    self.addComposition = function(drug) {
        drug.compositions.push({
            type: "",
            number: ""
        });
    };
 
    self.removeComposition = function(composition,formulation ) {
      formulation.compositions.remove(composition);
    };
 
    self.save = function() {
        self.lastSavedJson(JSON.stringify(ko.toJS(self.brandNames), null, 2));
    };
 
    self.lastSavedJson = ko.observable("")
};
 
ko.applyBindings(new brandNamesModel(initialData));        
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>
<div class='container'>
  <h2>brandNames</h2>
  <div>
    <table>
      <tr>
        <th>Brand name</th>
        <th>formulations</th>
      </tr>
      <tbody data-bind="foreach: brandNames">
        <tr>
          <td>
            <input data-bind='value: brandName' />
            <div><a href='#' data-bind='click: $root.removeBrandName'>Delete brand name</a></div>
          </td>
          <td>
            <table>
              <tbody data-bind="foreach: formulations">
                <tr>
                  <td><label>Formulation</label></td>
                  <td><select>
                                     <option>Tablet</option>
                                     <option>Syrap</option>
                                 </select>
                  </td>
                  <td><a href='#' data-bind='click: $root.removeFormulations'>Delete</a></td>


                  <td>
                    <table>
                      <tbody data-bind="foreach: compositions">
                        <tr>
                          <td><input data-bind='value: type' /></td>
                          <td><input data-bind='value: number' /></td>
                          <td><a href='#' data-bind='click: function() {$root.removeComposition($data, $parent) }'>Delete comp</a></td>
                        </tr>
                      </tbody>
                    </table>
                    <a href='#' data-bind='click: $root.addComposition'>Add another composition</a>
                  </td>
                </tr>

              </tbody>
            </table>
            <a href='#' data-bind='click: $root.addFormulations'>Add formulations</a>
          </td>

        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
  <p>
    <button data-bind='click: addBrandName'>Add a drug</button>
    <button data-bind='click: save, enable: brandNames().length > 0'>Save to JSON</button>
  </p>
  <textarea data-bind='value: lastSavedJson' rows='5' cols='60' disabled='disabled'> </textarea>
</div>
```

Comment: Wow! Really appreciate your effort. It's clear now.  :)